# An array of values. looping many times to calculate mean, closest matching array value, and then finding its index

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have an array of values. (`cols`)

I want to find out which index of `cols` contains the value closest to the mean of `cols`.

Can I combine these functions so that I'm not repeating loops?

```
let mean = cols.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr) / cols.length;
let closest = cols.reduce((prev, curr) => (curr - mean) < (prev - mean) ? curr : prev);
let meanCol = cols.indexOf(closest);
```

Comment: Seems like you are calculating the average, not the mean; https://byjus.com/maths/difference-between-average-and-mean/ If you wanted to actually find closest to mean, then you need only 1 loop.

Comment: Hmmm... Interesting, I actually came across that link before, but because it says multiple times that 'they can be used interchangeably' I took that to mean they're the same thing!

Also, I keep finding conflicting answers, such as this one saying that I am indeed doing mean:  https://www.purplemath.com/modules/meanmode.htm

Comment: Wikipedia agrees with you, so case closed for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the last line searching for the index since you can get the index in the reduce method.

Btw, you forgot to add `Math.abs` to deal with positive value when comparing.

Demo:

```js
const cols = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]

const mean = cols.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr, 0) / cols.length;

const { value, index } = cols.reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
    // You have deal in absolute 
    if (Math.abs(curr - mean) < Math.abs(prev.value - mean)) {
        return { value: curr, index: i }
    } else {
        return prev
    }
}, { value: cols[0], index: 0 });

console.log({ mean, value, index })
```

Answer (score 2):

A short review;

- You can't reduce an empty array, I would check for empty arrays and decide how to deal with them
- Have a think about `let` vs. `const`, `mean` and `closest` should probably be `const`
- You want that code in a properly named function